# Split Files into multiple files/arrays - perl

Tags: perl

I want to split a text file into multiple files based on content using perl sripting.
My file content is as below...

```
    Header1:123 
    data... 
    1234... 

    SubTitle1:HHHHHHH 
    mmmm 
    aaaaa  

    SubTitle2:QQQQQQQ 
    mmmm 
    aaaaa 

    Header:MMMMMMMMMMM 
    datasadsad... 
    123434324... 

    SubTitle1:HHHHHHH 
    mmmm343343243
    aaaaa dsfdfds 

    SubTitle2:QQQQQQQ 
    mmmm sff
    aaaaasfsdf
```

And I want to split this file as below....

File 1 or array or anyobject to hold this....

```
    Header1:123 
    data... 
    1234... 

    SubTitle1:HHHHHHH 
    mmmm 
    aaaaa  

    SubTitle2:QQQQQQQ 
    mmmm 
    aaaaa
```

File2  as     below..

```
    Header:MMMMMMMMMMM 
    datasadsad... 
    123434324... 

    SubTitle1:HHHHHHH 
    mmmm343343243
    aaaaa dsfdfds 

    SubTitle2:QQQQQQQ 
    mmmm sff
    aaaaasfsdf
```

Please help me on this!

Comment: Hey guys, be a little less trigger happy with the close question button! People need help with algorithms, not just code.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $fh;
while (<>) {
   if (/^Header/) {
      open($fh, '>', ...) or die $!;
   }

   print($fh $_);
}
```

Comment: Fingers were on autopilot. Fixed.

Comment: This is not working...can u pls explain little bit abt this code...

Comment: @user1823133 What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Not sure what there is to explain. What do you not understand? (argh, can't type!)

Comment: I am very new to perl programming..and trying  to understand reg exp..     u have not initialized the var $fh and 'open(...)' statement has some dots... I dont uunderstand...

Comment: It matches strings that start with "Header"